# couldn't use variable from included file

Tags: javascript

this is my code beetwen script tag :

```
        function open()
        {
            file = "Test1.js";
            document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='"+file+"'></scr"+"ipt>");
            document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = doc;
        }
```

content of Test1.js is "var doc = hello wolrd' ".But why it doesn't showed..

any one can help me??

Answer (score 4):

`doc` won't be assigned until `Test1.js` is executed, and that won't be executed until your current script has finished executing.

If you want something to happen after `Test1.js` has loaded an executed, you'll need to [check for its load event](http://stevesouders.com/efws/script-onload.php).

Comment: I thought that closing and opening a script (`</script><script>`) will load and execute scripts that were document.written inside the previous one, so you don't have to use an `onload` event listener.

Comment: @Marcel, yes, but the OP is trying to access `doc` in the same function that wrote the script tag.